# RequireJS structure – build, including, general questions

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I don't understand how to properly use RequireJS on a small homepage project. Using the optimizer makes stuff even more confusing to me.

What is missing for me is a bit of a **general structure**.

- Is it wise to have a file, i.e. `common.js`, that is *always* loaded? If so, should it be loaded using `data-main`, or is it better to follow [this simple template](https://github.com/volojs/create-template)?

Here, the file loaded using `data-main` holds only the config and requires the main application code as dependency (which means already two http requests, could by fixed by optimizer I guess):

```
// For any third party dependencies, like jQuery, place them in the lib folder.

// Configure loading modules from the lib directory,
// except for 'app' ones, which are in a sibling
// directory.
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});

// Start loading the main app file. Put all of
// your application logic in there.
requirejs(['app/main']);
```

- When using the optimizer, I noticed by default `findNestedDependencies` is set to `false`, which means dependencies declared using a `require()` call inside a `require()` call won't be taken into account. Does that mean the optimized code should really only contain the main code – the core of an application that is used everywhere, more or less – and it's still okay to async load certain dependencies?
- How am I supposed to include `require.js` in my build? I tried listing it as a dependency for the core, but that would mean I have to stop using

`<script data-main="assets/js/common" src="assets/js/vendor/require.js"></script>`

because otherwise, it would be loaded twice (one time as dependency for `common.js`, one time because it's in the `src` attribute).

To only load it once, I would directly include `common.js`, which then loads `require.js` as dependency – seems a bit strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it wise to have a file, i.e. `common.js`, that is always loaded? If so, should it be loaded using `data-main`, or is it better to follow this simple template?

This is **wholly** dependent on the details of the project. A large project where time-to-usability is important will have to do things differently than a tiny project. There's no one-size-fits-all here.

> When using the optimizer, I noticed by default `findNestedDependencies` is set to `false`, which means dependencies declared using a `require()` call inside a `require()` call won't be taken into account.

It means that `require()` calls inside `require()` calls *or* `define()` calls won't be used to determine the entire list of dependencies.

> Does that mean the optimized code should really only contain the main code – the core of an application that is used everywhere, more or less – and it's still okay to async load certain dependencies?

RequireJS always load dependencies asynchronously. `findNestedDependencies` changes nothing. Probably you mean "still okay to *optionally* load certain dependencies". Yes, it is okay. I do it in one of my projects.

Note that `findNestedDependencies` has no bearing on `r.js`'s ability to trace optional dependencies. If `findNestedDependencies` is `true` and you do this:

```
define(function () {
    if (some_condition) {
        require(["blah"]);
    }
});
```

and this module is included in a build, then `blah` will also be included. RequireJS has no way to determine whether or not the `some_condition` would constantly be `false`. Conversely, if you do:

```
define(function () {
    var deps = [];
    if (some_condition) {
        deps.push("blah");
    }
    require(deps);
});
```

then `r.js` will never include `blah` in the build because it is not doing source interpretation to the level required to realize that, like in the first case, `blah` *may* be needed. So in the latter case *you* have to make sure that the core of the application will be able to find `blah` at run time. Typically, this means having a build configuration for `r.js` that will use a `modules` array to define a bundle for the core, and bundles for each group of modules to be loaded optionally.

> How am I supposed to include `require.js` in my build?

It is possible to create a bundle that includes RequireJS in it so that you do not have to list RequireJS separately. It is documented [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html):

> If you want to include require.js with the main.js source, you can use this kind of command:
>
> ```
> node ../../r.js -o baseUrl=. paths.requireLib=../../require name=main include=requireLib out=main-built.js
> ```
>
> Since "require" is a reserved dependency name, you create a "requireLib" dependency and map it to the require.js file.
>
> Once that optimization is done, you can change the script tag to reference "main-built.js" instead of "require.js", and your optimized project will only need to make one script request.

Comment: Thanks again for your help – your answer couldn't be better!